# Docker Desktop always switches or create to 'desktop-linux' context on launch

Tags: linux, docker

1. On launch system docker context is 'default': $> ***docker context ls***

```
    NAME               TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                     
    default *          moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                                                
    desktop-linux      moby                Docker Desktop                            unix:///home/username/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
```

And by command ***docker images*** I see:

```
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
hello-world   latest    9c7a54a9a43c   4 months ago   13.3kB
```

2. I switch context to desktop-linux: $> ***docker context use desktop-linux***

And launch Docker Desktop

Command ***docker context*** ls out

```
NAME               TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                     
default            moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                                                
desktop-linux *    moby                Docker Desktop                            unix:///home/username/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
```

Also docker images list is empty

3. If I delete context 'desktop-linux', and create 'desktop-linux' with endpoint unix:///var/run/docker.sock, then on subsequent launch, Docker Desktop create old context again.

How to launch Docker Desktop in 'default' context with DOCKER ENDPOINT unix:///var/run/docker.sock ?